# Preventing Powershell from adopting Windows Explorer options

Tags: windows, powershell, zip, windows-explorer

I don't do much with Powershell often but yesterday was needing to extract a file from a zip archive. During the process I was looking for a file by iterating through the contents of a zip anbd comparing the file's (item) Name property to the filename (say abc.ps1).

Code was working locally and I was happy with the result I was getting.
Pushe the code to deployment environment to be run on server and the code was notifying me that it could not find abc.ps1.
Further investigation, I logged onto the server (as my own account, not the service account that the code executed as). When I looked in the zip it was querying I could see the file, but it was named abc.
I had xyz.txt and def.pdf but the ps1 file was simply abc. I knew that this is based on an Option in Windows Explorer options for 'Hide extensions for known file types'.

Logging on to the server with the service account, unchecking this option and re-running the script fixed all problems, it was able to fid the file based on name + ext.

Is there a way of enforcing PS not to take into account Explorer options such as these when running?

Am currently thinking of applying a GPO to prevent any systems from having this option on.

Comment: That sounds like a red-herring to me. Powershell does NOT use explorer settings.

Comment: Take a look: http://postimg.org/image/gnbb9pfid/

Comment: Perhaps you tab completed `basename`? I don't think this is a thing